# video editing tool to color overlay a specific part

Tags: windows, ubuntu, video-editing, watermark

I have downloaded a video from YouTube. But the publisher has put some link (their twitter and facebook) for promotional purpose. The links keeps coming up through out the video in the black area (up and down of the video which are black). Thank god that links are on the black part of the video otherwise it would be hard to remove.

[image]

Also I want to remove the last few seconds of the video.

**I don't want to crop that part (the link or bottom part)**. The video is in **MP4** format. I **don't want to lose the quality** in anyway, I won't mind if the file size increases.

I want a opensource and free tool. Good if it is available to both Windows and Ubuntu.

Here is a [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GYi4n_gHUc&hd=1) to the video.

Comment: What do you men by: "I want to remove the the last few seconds of the video. I don't want to crop that part."?

Comment: Don't read those sentences together. **I want to remove the last few seconds of the video** means that I simply don't want that part. And **I don't want to crop that part** means I don't want to crop the link  part (where the arrow is pointing) as that would change the resolution. By the way I have edited the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Video-editing software for Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/87299/video-editing-software-for-windows-7) and/or [Looking For Video Editing Software for Ubuntu](http://superuser.com/questions/5822/looking-for-video-editing-software-for-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Try [VideoPad](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CGYQFjAB&url=http://www.nchsoftware.com/videopad/index.html&ei=DUTkT9KBDMjJrAeFqoWICQ&usg=AFQjCNFOb3O2cqY6UnTrMmrObBhQ2zoYew&sig2=SVRnwO3yiIIVL95aqjz7JA), this is a good video editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Avidemux**](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) for both removing the watermark and deleting the last part of the video clip. It supports mp4 as well.

**Note**: To remove the watermark, just Go to

> Filters > Misc > Add png as logo

.